# null value for solution sharepoint

Tags: list

i have created a method in console to get the value from master list and then change the value in another list field. but it is giving exeption for null value.

Code:

```
public static void GetListItems()
    {

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            try
            {
                string strSiteURL = @"http://";

                using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(strSiteURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.RootWeb)
                    {
                        //Step1: get all the list items
                        string listName = "Acccess Tracker";
                        SPList objList = spWeb.Lists[listName];
                        SPListItemCollection items = objList.Items;

                        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                        {

                            string strStatus = Convert.ToString(item["Status"]);
                            string strSyncAD = Convert.ToString( item["SyncWithAD"]);
                            //Step2: check if status for approved and sync Ad as Yes/No
                            if (strStatus == "Approved" && strSyncAD == "False")
                            {
                                string objSite = Convert.ToString( item["Site"]);
                                string objFunc = Convert.ToString(item["Functionality"]);
                                string strADgroupName = GetADGroupName(spWeb, objSite, objFunc);

                                // Step 3: check if AD group name is returned and add to AD group
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strADgroupName))
                                {
                                    SPFieldUserValueCollection userValue = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(spWeb, Convert.ToString(item["UserName"]));
                                    string strUserName = string.Empty;
                                    foreach (SPFieldUserValue spUser in userValue)
                                    {
                                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spUser.User.Email))
                                            strUserName = spUser.User.LoginName;
                                    }
                                    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    // Step:4 Finally adding User to ADgroup.
                                    AddUserToGroup(strUserName, strADgroupName);
                                    item["SyncWithAD"] = "True"; // update SyncwithAD status
                                    item.Update();
                                   // item.SystemUpdate();
                                    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No approved User who need access!!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //TODO: Handle exception logging
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                EventLog.WriteEntry("Access tracker- Alert Job", "getMislist method - " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error, 15001);

            }
        });         
    }
```

Comment: The full exception and where it is occurring would be useful. Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger?

Comment: i have used debugger and value is showing for each of them, I get exeption when it pass through item.update

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, don't convert the object without null checking it, as you do in "`Convert.ToString(item["Status"]);`", if the object is null, then "`Convert.ToString(...)` will fail. instead you can do the following,

```
string objSite = item["Site"]!= null ? Convert.ToString( item["Site"]): String.Empty;
```

Comment: i didn't get it. Can you please explain again. Thanks

Comment: The convert method will fail if item["Status"] is null. You need to use the conditional operator (?) to ensure an exception is not thrown. So it logically would be: set objSite to item["Site"] value, converted to string, if it is not null otherwise set it to an empty string.